# Pandas csv field separation logic

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a mini csv file with one row and only two columns (no headers):

```
"1,6 Engine DCT 18\"","1,6 Engine Luxury DCT"
```

My intention is to read it using Pandas and get a one-row table with two columns/values:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1,6 Engine DCT 18" | 1,6 Engine Luxury DCT |

If I don't specify and quote and escape character and just run

`pandas.read_csv("mycsv.csv", header=None, sep=",")`

the way it splits the data is confusing to me. It will output this:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1,6 Engine DCT 18\",1 | 6 Engine Luxury DCT" |

Could anyone explain why exactly this is the split? I am surprised about the ending of the first field, I don't get why the ,*1* is included in the first field and not the second. I know I can specify *quotechar='"'* and *escapechar="\\"* in *pandas.read_csv()* and then the split will be the expected one, but I'm wondering what exactly pandas is doing to arrive at the rather unexpected (at least to me) split. I am using pandas 2.0.1 although I suspect it's not about the version but my lack of fundamental understanding on how it splits text fields and handles special characters by default.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `doublequote=False` parameter to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to avoid having the `""` in `\""` being interpreted as an escape character:

```
pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', header=None, sep=',', doublequote=False)
```

Output:

```
                     0                      1
0  1,6 Engine DCT 18\"  1,6 Engine Luxury DCT
```

Comment: Thank you. I mentioned in my post I know how I can solve this very problem. What I struggle with is understanding why the default behaviour was what it was in the first place, more specifically, why the ",1" part gets attached to the end of the first field, why that part is interpreted to still belong to the first field.